# Is there a more "logic" form of programming this function?

Tags: python

I finally make this works, but I dont like that my solution is like "someone else checking how many list exist" and writing the code.

It find common item in all list.

I tried to use recursion, but I coldn't make it works

```
def comunes (*lista):
  word = ""
  for i in lista:
    word = "set({})".format(i) + " &" + word
  word = word.split(" ")
  word.pop()
  wordF = ""
  for i in word:
    wordF += str(i)
  if len(eval(wordF)) == 0:
    return None
  else:
    return eval (wordF)
```

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on the problem you're trying to solve? You almost definitely do not need eval() for this.

Comment: Or turning something into a weird string only to parse it back again

Comment: Are you sure that this works?

Comment: Yes it works. The solution that @isaactfa is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def comunes(*lista):
    commons = set(lista[0])
    for i in lista[1:]:
        commons &= set(i)
    return commons
```

This function creates a set `commons` with all the elements of the first list and then for each next list `i` it'll replace `commons` with the intersection (`&` operator) of `commons` with the set of `i`. The intersection of two sets is the set with only the elements that are both in the first *and* the second set. This'll ensure that `commons` has only elements that are in all the lists you passed to `comunes`.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you're using `eval` or `exec` you should rethink your approach. It's almost never a good idea to use them for 'everyday' problems.